# jQuery .each element in other URL content

Tags: jquery

This is the third time I've tried getting help with this on stackoverflow.
Basically what I am trying to do is get a url page, then grab content from each element 'tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0'.

Everything about the code is working except the innermost .each loop.  I believe I have just wrote the each function wrong.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: this has been solved san substr, which is just an error.  Thanks all.

```
var allLessonsArray= new Array();
$.each(lessonInTopicSectionArray, function(index, lesson){   
    var lastAttempt = 0;
    url='------/learn/mod/lesson/report.php?id='+lesson.id+'&action=reportdetail&userid='+userid+'&try='+lastAttempt;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var lessonArray= new Array();
        $('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').html(data).each(function(index, content) {
            alert(jQuery(content).html());
            score=parseInt(content.substr(content.length - 1));
            lessonArray[index]=score;
        });     
    allLessonsArray[index]={name:lesson.name, score: lessonArray};  
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What happens when you use the code? In other words: what goes wrong, where the result differs from what you expected?

Comment: By what do you mean you are trying to "grab the content from each tr...", right now you are setting the content to whatever is returned from your ajax call ?

Comment: Well, I use alert and firebug to debug.  alert(score) doesn't work.  Also, firebug shows the documents taking a couple seconds to load.  I'm not sure if this is an issue here though.

If the code were working correctly, alert(score) would repeat 6 times.  It doesn't here.

Comment: @NathanLothamer: Is the call performed (do you see every call in the network tab)? Do you call the same domain, or something else?

Comment: @Koerner As far as I can tell, the selector is correct.

Comment: @Tadeck I call the same domain, just a different page.  Firebug loads both documents, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @NathanLothamer: How the `url` starts? I am interested in the part before first slash.

Comment: @Tadeck The -------- are used for privacy reasons.

Comment: @NathanLothamer: In other words: 1) does it start with "`http://`" or "`https://`"? I already know what is probably an issue, but it is worth asking anyway.

Comment: @Tadeck - does it really matter? Right now Nathan is selecting an element in the DOM that probably does not exist, then trying to set it's inner HTML to the data retrieved from the ajax call, and then trying to iterate over the element that probably does not exist, and not getting much of a result and no alerts, obviously ?

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, it does matter, as we still do not know what was the issue. He may be hitting SOP without knowing it. I do not see the code, I do not know for sure. Anyway, I think you should try to understand the goal of this code. I think I understand it - see my answer. If you have other ideas, post your own answer.

Comment: Did you notice that I answered the same as you did 25 minutes ago in the comment above?

Comment: @adeneo What I want to do- grab the content from the page, select the each element of that name, then store the content from this element in an array.  How do I rewrite this line so it does work the way you are saying?

Comment: @adeneo: You did not answer what he asked. Even I did not understand what you meant. After solving the issue myself I understand what you meant. The idea is to provide the solution for others in a clear way, not in a way that they will understand after solving it. Furthermore, we post answers as _answers_, not as _comments_. If you wish, add it yourself. But please, be more clear now. No offence.

Comment: @NathanLothamer: Read my answer. It explains what you are doing and what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
$('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').html(data)
```

you are actually selecting cells and replacing them with retrieved data. What you meant was probably this:

```
$(data).find('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0')
```

which will execute "`tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0`" selector on retrieved documents.

Comment: The Javascript is run on the same domain that the URL is being open.  I'm pretty sure there is a jQuery solution to this, too, which is all we can load in the header atm.

Comment: @NathanLothamer: Nathan, please read my updated answer - this has nothing to do with Same Origin Policy now, since you are saying this is the same domain and, according to you, it gets the content (just make sure you will not switch protocols unwillingly). My answer is about on which you execute `.each()`.

Comment: I bet that is what I meant.  Let me give it a shot.  Also, will this work with each?

Comment: $(data).find('tr.r1.lastrow td.cell.c0').each(function(index, content) 

--as content is alerted as  [object HTMLTableCellElement], not the string that it is supposed to be.

Comment: @NathanLothamer: Ok, I forgot about one thing. You are now (after applying this answer) iterating through DOM elements (cells), so to get the content, you will need to do `jQuery(content).html()` instead of just using `content` inside `.each()`. In other words, `content` is not enough.

Comment: Excellent.  This is the answer.  Thanks, very much. We've been at this one for the last few days trying to figure it out.